# New session id after being redirected with Zend Framework 1

Tags: php, zend-framework, session, sessionid, zend-session

I'm having a hard tackling a problem with a Zend Framework 1 application. It's a custom webshop application where from the checkout page the client is being redirected to a payment gateway provider. So it looks like this:

1. When the client chooses a payment method on our checkout page behind the scenes a transaction handshake is being done between my application and the payment provider.
2. The payment provider then sends me back a payment url to which the client is redirected.
3. The client pays and the payment provider redirects the client back to our webshop to a success url.

In most cases this works perfectly fine, but in some occasions the client gets a new session id after being redirected to our success page. This is a problem because the session data is being used at that point to complete the order.

Locally I've only been able to reproduce this problem once out of probably 50 tries. So it's one of those "sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't scenarios" or in other words a pain in the *** to debug and fix.

I tried playing around with the session settings in my application.ini and also the _initSession in my Bootstrap, but in fact after those changes I managed to reproduce the problem (that one time).

The original application.ini and Bootstrap.php (relevant pieces only) look like this:

application.ini:

```
  resources.session.save_path = APPLICATION_PATH "/../data/sessions"
  resources.session.gc_maxlifetime = 2592000
  resources.session.remember_me_seconds = 2592000
```

Bootstrap.php:

```
  protected function _initSession()
  {
     // set up the session as per the config.
     $options = $this->getOptions();

     $sessionOptions = $options['resources']['session'];

     Zend_Session::setOptions($sessionOptions);
     Zend_Session::start();
  }
```

Note that in all other circumstances/use-cases the sessions are working fine throughout the site. It's only after the redirecting that it goes wrong for some clients. I had the application logging extra information and I could actually see the session id change in those cases.

Could it have something to do with the long session lifetime (1 month)? Or do I have to call Zend_Session::rememberMe(...); after Zend_Session::start() in the Bootstrap? Or any other ideas, tips and advice?

Edit: 
The other session options I experimented with are as follows:

```
resources.session.name = myuniquesessionname
resources.session.use_cookies = on
resources.session.use_only_cookies = on
resources.session.save_path = APPLICATION_PATH "/../data/sessions" 
resources.session.gc_maxlifetime = 2592000
resources.session.remember_me_seconds = 2592000
resources.session.strict = on
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fought with this very issue, and found that I was dealing with two different domains. Some of my users were starting out on *mydomain.com* and then after finishing with the payment provider they were getting redirected back to *www.mydomain.com*. This would result in a completely new session.

Possible that this is your issue?

If so, I would stick something like this early on in the bootstrap process, possibly right at the top of your index.php file:

```
if($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] != 'www.mydomain.com') {
   Header("Location: http://www.mydomain.com" . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
   exit;
}
```

This assures right up front that users are using the domain that you want them to use. The redirect will preserve the full url, with any GET variables.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I just did a quick test and it looks like this is the problem. The payment provider redirects to the URL without www and the clients that had this problem used the www prefix. How did you solve this? I guess I could use a rewrite rule in htaccess or is there an option for Zend_Session to make the session only rely on the domain no matter what prefix?

Comment: I don't think you can make the session work on both domains. In my case the redirect url was dynamic, I could specify it each time with my third-party provider, and made sure that the redirect url used the same domain that the user was coming from. The other option would be to check the domain in your bootstrap file, and force (redirect) users to the domain you want them to use up front.

Comment: Have not tried it myself, but this might be [an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1781453/zend-authentication-problem-with-subdomain).

Comment: Updated my answer, I think a simple domain check and forced redirect would be the simplest answer.

Comment: Thanks guys. I got it solved now. I didn't have to use a redirect, I'll outline it in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was the following:
The problem was indeed the domain of the session cookie. In my application.ini I added:

resources.session.cookie_domain = .mydomainname.com
Where obviously mydomainname.com is the domainname of the webshop.

Now after this and clearing my cookies in my developer Firefox everything worked. I log in to the site without using the www. prefix and after if I go to the site using the URL including the www. prefix I'm still using the same session.

I cleared all the sessions at the server-side.
However in my other non-developer browsers where I didn't clear the cookies I still had the problem that the session id was being re-used, because of the existing cookies that were tied to the specific domainnames. So for example in my Safari I stil got two sessions whenever I browsed to the two different URL's and everytime the same session id's would be used. To fix this I simply added the name of the session in application.ini:

resources.session.name = NEWSESSID

So the browser gets forced to create a new cookie with the new name instead of the default PHPSESSID.

Looks like everything is working again now. Thanks a lot for the help, much appreciated!